# Calculating $E[Y]$, $\sigma(y^2)$ and $\sigma(y)$

Tags: statistics

Using the following data:

\begin{matrix}\hline
\text{# of fires}&0&1&2&3&4&5\\\hline
\text{Probability}&0.22 &0.34 &0.25 &0.13 &0.05 &0.01\\\hline
\end{matrix}

How to calculate?

a. $E[Y]$
b. $\sigma(y^2)$
c. $\sigma(y)$

Thanks!

Comment: # of fires 0,1,2 3,4 corresponds to a given probabilities. 0 with 0.22, 1 with 0.34...

Comment: What is Oy^2 and Oy?

Comment: Oy^2 stands for Ơ(sigma)y^2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean $\sigma^2(y)$, so c is just the square root of $b$.  To get a mean, just multiply values by probabilities and sum them up.  To get a variance, first square the values, then multiply the values by the probabilities, then sum them up, then subtract $\bigl(E(Y)\bigr)^2$ from the value you get.